# Bootstrap 3: Responsive navbar opens off-canvas on the left instead of default behaviour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm starting a new project with Bootstrap 3, and I need that clicking on "*Sandwich*" icon in responsive view, **will open collapsed navbar from left side off-canvas instead from the top like in default behaviour**.

I'm surprised when I see that in official documentation there is only [**this Example**](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/), that anyway is putting off-canvas a sidebar and not main navigation bar...

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom css:

```
.navbar-toggle {
   float: left;
   margin-left: 15px;
}
```

This will basically override the bootstrap css that forces the toggle to float right.  Make sure the put your custom css link tag AFTER the bootstrap css link tag.